# How to make Doctrine delete table prefixes from class names?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 1.1.5 and I'd like to know if there is some option for remove table prefix from files and class names when calling *Doctrine::generateModelsFromDb* or *Doctrine::generateModelsFromYaml*.

Edit:
For example I have tables like mo_article, mo_language, mo_article_text, etc.  When Doctrine generates the models (using the functions from above), the class names will be MoArticle, MoLanguage, MoArticleText, ... but I want them to be Article, Language, ArticleText... Is there some option in those functions to avoid adding table prefixes in model class names?

Thank you

Comment: What table prefixes are you talking about? Doctrine doesn't add anything to the table names when it generates the models. Do you have an example?

Comment: Hi Chris, I've edited the question and added an example.thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same scenario and ended up writing my own function to solve it.  This function goes through my YAML file, reads each table name, and adds the appropriate `className:` entry without the table prefix.

Here's the function:

```
const TABLE_PFX = 'tableName:';
const CLASS_PFX = 'className:';

function AddClassNames($yamlPath) {

  $tempFilePath = $yamlPath . '.old';
  rename($yamlPath, $tempFilePath);
  $tempFile = fopen($tempFilePath, 'r');
  $yamlFile = fopen($yamlPath, 'w');

  while (!feof($tempFile)) {
      $line = fgets($tempFile);
      fwrite($yamlFile, $line);
      if ($index = strpos($line, TABLE_PFX)) {
          $tableName = trim(substr($line, $index + strlen(TABLE_PFX) + 1));
          $className = substr($tableName, 4);
          $className = strtocamel($className);
          $classLine = str_replace(TABLE_PFX, CLASS_PFX, $line);
          $classLine = str_replace($tableName, $className, $classLine);
          fwrite($yamlFile, $classLine);
      }
  }
  fclose($tempFile);
  fclose($yamlFile);
  unlink($tempFilePath);
}
```

And here's how I use it:

```
Doctrine_Core::generateYamlFromDb($yamlPath);
AddClassNames($yamlPath);
Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromYaml($yamlPath, 'models',
    array('doctrine'), 
    array('generateTableClasses' => true,));
```

One further note - with this method you don't have the luxury of Doctrine converting your `database_table_name` to the PHP-friendly `ClassName`, so you have to do this yourself.  I used the `strtocamel` function from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php#94465).

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
className: CorrectName
```

to each table definition you need to change in your schema.yml file. Doctrine will generate all the files with the CorrectName pattern but still read/write from your prefixed table.